# Silverlight querystring alternative

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I see there are similar posts on this topic but none answer my question. I am navigating to a silverlight page and I need to pass a value to the page. For security reasons, I cant use querystring.

What are the alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Why is that considered insecure?  Can you encrypt the querstring value(s) then decrypt them on the page?  Please elaborate.

Comment: To a Silverlight page from another Silverlight page or from an HTML page?

Comment: Its insecure becuase I am passing a ID value: If I pass it in the querystring, it could be changed by the user and use that to navigate to other data. The value originates in my View Model which then nvigates to a silverlight page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add it to an Application Context object that can be shared between views.  I use this approach in my current project e.g.

```
    public class ApplicationContext
    {

        #region Declarations

        // Static instance of the application class.
        private static ApplicationContext _instance;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public ApplicationContext()
        {
        }

        // Static instance creator.
        public static ApplicationContext Instance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new ApplicationContext();
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        //Shared properties e.g. Is available between all views
        public SecurityContext UserContext { get; set; }
     }
```

To use from a view:

```
CurrentUserContext = ApplicationContext.Instance().UserContext
```

So, before you navigate from one view to another simply populate relevant shared properties in the ApplicationContext object that can then be retrieved by other views.

Comment: Great - thats just what I was looking for. Thanks Myles J

Answer (score 1):

you can use InitParams.
////set in aspx

          
          
          
          
          " />

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  var coll=e.InitParams;
}

Comment: I cant use InitParams because the value changes based on user selection

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value on the web server (via your RIA data model, or post in any manner you like), then request the value when you navigate to the new page.

Comment: I cant do it that way because its a value selected by the user on the previous page

Comment: Of course you can.  You can post the value when they select it in the UI (think AJAX if it helps).

Comment: I was under the impression that passing values could all be done client side without the need to go back to the server?

Answer (score 0):

if it's between silverlight views, then you can have some static data bag to pass data around. [This post](http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2009/09/17/making-a-http-post-in-silverlight-a-k-a-thread-hopping/) on how to make HTTP Post in Silverlight might help you as well.

Comment: I tried ususing the NavigationFramework to hide the URL but I am getting errors in the XAML : The error says the ? char is invalid ???

Comment: <navigationCore:UriMapping Uri='Structures'
MappedUri='/Views/OwnerOccupierHome.xaml?StructureID={0}'></navigationCore:UriMapping>

Comment: use the *double quotes* **"**, instead of the single quote **'**.

Comment: Single or double quotes make no difference